# Cost of a travel in UK

Tags: uk, budget, standard-visitor-visas

I am preparing a new application for a Family Visa in UK after a refusal
I stay at my brother's house in Birmingham for a week of my leave limit

My salary is £420 and I started my current job on June 4, 2017.

Question: that it's just questions I made in attached picture

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  It's not clear what you're looking for - can you clarify your question?

Comment: Are you going to travel in UK or are you staying in Birmingham for a week...

Comment: @Thameur If I’ve understood correctly you want to know if proposed calculations look feasible. You earn £420pm, you spend £100 and give £120 to your family = £200 remaining. You are going to spend £600 on the trip (flight £270, expenses £330), this represents 3 months’ worth of savings, almost all of the £700 you state you have available. IMHO I’d say this is borderline at best; if you didn’t have a previous refusal your chances might be higher but reapplying so quickly may influence the ECO to decide that the cost is still out of line with your income/savings.

Comment: @traveller Yes exactly these about calculates And I understood then the answer of the question ((What is the cost to you personally of your trip)) = ((Cost of airplane, boat or train tickets + The cost of your living expenses)) that's it –